# make file to load last using php

Tags: javascript, php, .htaccess

i have a code that will name my file randomly, but what i am trying to make is also it loads the file when the page is completely loaded

here's my code

```
<?php
function random_string($length) {
    $key = '';
    $keys = array_merge(range(0, 9), range('a', 'z'));

    for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
        $key .= $keys[array_rand($keys)];
    }

    return "../../myfolder/js-".$key.".js"; // Change here
}
?>
```

on my page body i use this

```
<?php echo '<script data-cfasync="false" type="text/javascript" src="'.random_string(50).'"></script>'; ?>
```

and on .htaccess i use this

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^myfolder/js\-([a-z0-9]+)\.js/?$ myfolder/file.js
```

i only need with this to load at last when page is completely loaded
and yes i have placed it at the bottom of my page but it doesn't load at last

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "load at last when page is completely loaded?" If the `script` tag is at the bottom of the `body`, it will be the last script loaded. If you mean you don't want to load it until after the document *renders*, then you need to add a handler for that.

Comment: Have you ever thought of using an AJAX concat loader with a request as the user scrolls, or multiple requests until the javascript engine receives a stop requesting order?

Comment: This line: `$key .= $keys[array_rand($keys)];` should be like this: `$key .= array_rand($keys);` for it (to have a chance) to work.